Suitable use of 'boost::asio::placeholders::error'
The code snippet below is seen at this page.
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class con_handler : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<con_handler>
{
private:
  tcp::socket sock;
  std::string message="Hello From Server!";
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data[max_length];
    
public:
    
typedef boost::shared_ptr<con_handler> pointer;
 con_handler(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : sock(io_service)
  {
  }

  static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  {
    return pointer(new con_handler(io_service));
  }
  
  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return sock;
  }

  void start()
  {
    sock.async_read_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length),
        boost::bind(&con_handler::handle_read,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    
    sock.async_write_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(message, max_length),
        boost::bind(&con_handler::handle_write, 
            shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& err,
                   size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!err) {
      cout << data << endl;

            

    } else {
std::cerr << "err (recv): " << err.message() << std::endl;
      sock.close();
    }
  }
  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& err,
               size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!err) {
 
    cout << "Server sent Hello message!"<< endl;
    
    } else {
      std::cerr << "err (recv): " << err.message() << std::endl;
      sock.close();
    }
  }

};

class Server {

private:
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

void start_accept()
  {
    // creates a socket
    con_handler::pointer connection =
      con_handler::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

    // initiates an asynchronous accept operation 
    // to wait for a new connection. 
    acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, connection,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
public:
  Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service): acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1234))
  { 
     start_accept();
}
    

  void handle_accept(con_handler::pointer connection,
                     const boost::system::error_code& err)
  {
    if (!err) {
      connection->start();
    }
    start_accept();
  }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  try 
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;   
    Server server(io_service);
    io_service.run();

} 
catch(std::exception& e) 
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
  return 0;
}

I think the code snippet should be improved.
Since asio::placeholders::error is equivalent to placeholders::_1 and const boost::system::error_code& err is the second parameter for the void Server::handle_accept(con_handler::pointer connection, const boost::system::error_code& err), the boost::asio::placeholders::error should be replaced by boost::placeholders::_2 in the code below.
acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(),
  boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, connection,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error));


If they're equivalent, why is one better than the other?

@sehe What confused me is that const boost::system::error_code& err is the second parameter for the  void Server::handle_accept(con_handler::pointer connection, const boost::system::error_code& err) , the boost::asio::placeholders::error(i.e. boost::placeholders::_1) should be replaced by boost::placeholders::_2  in the the code below. Where am I wrong?

Luckily I sensed that confusion, so my answer explained it

I'm a bit confused. Did you see the explanation? Did it help?

@sehe Thank you for he detailed explaination. I have read your answer several times. But it's a pity I don't understand it. The question still confuses me now.

I fear I wrote too much. What if you focus on the answer BEFORE "Meanwhile, "? The rest is a code review unrelated to the bind placeholder. You are confusing the handler interface (void(error_code)) with the implementation you bind to it (which can have any number of arguments). The placeholder number refers to the bound interface so, _1 is actually correct. Note that you bind this  and connection into the other parameters, so only the one placeholder remains.

@sehe Thank you for the thorough explanation and the code review. After I read your lastest comment, I suddenly understand it. I think there are two ways to understand it. 1. As you mentioned that this and connection have been bound already
and the sequece for the placeholder should be increased one by one, say _1, _2, _3, since there is only one argument has not been binded, so _1 is the right choice.  Too long, please see the next comment.

2.  No matter how many parameters would be bound by the programmer, the interface for handler is confirmed which only needs one argument, therefore only _1 is needed. In other words, once the interface for handler(i.e. void(error_code)) is fixed by the library, the boost::asio::placeholders::error  is always equivalent to _1. I think both of these two explanations are right, while the latter one is better. How do you think about it?

Correct. I think of it as transforming an interface, and the placeholders select from the target interface (the "future input"). Things can get pretty wild: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/704d78db5cc299e8

@sehe Wonderful example code! I have never seen such usage before ! As you say that the placeholders select from the target interface (the "future input"), the future input for handler(i.e. void(error_code)) is passed by the asio itself when a connection is coming or something goes wrong. Am I right?

Yes  

@sehe Thank you so much. My understanding of this matter is at a deeper level with your generous help. If I undertstand you correctly, if the handler (i.e. void(error_code)) is called as handler("no_meaning_arg", "no_meaning_arg", err) in the asio library, then  _3 should be the right choice( i.e acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(), boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, connection, _3)); ). Am I right?

It seem that the last my comment is impossible. I find it's impossible to call complete_handler("no_meaning_arg", "no_meaning_arg", err) in the asio library when calling the complete handler since the handler's signature is already defined as void(error_code)

Yes to both. If Asio did that, that would work, and yes boost doesn't do that ;)

If you were thinking of the position of the parameter (_1), it is correct because the handler signature is (docs):
void handler(
    const boost::system::error_code& error // Result of operation.
);

Note that the bind expression is your handler, not handle_accept (which takes 3 arguments, including the this argument).
If you think _1 is more expressive, go for it.
Meanwhile,

don't use Boost Bind global placeholders (include <boost/bind/bind.hpp> or configure the compiler definitions)
better yet replace boost::bind with std::bind
replace boost::shared_ptr and boost::enable_shared_from_this with std::xxx
use type aliases instead of typedefs
don't have unused arguments (like bytes_transferred); specifically DO NOT rely on NUL-termination of data!
don't use using namespace indiscriminately
don't use C-style arrays
don't overspecify buffer size (it's a source of errors)
catch exceptions by const&
make handle_XYZ private
no need to sock.close() on error; you can cancel any async operations chains and let con_handler's destructor handle it. In your case,  even cancel is redundant because there is no async loop(s), and the single read/write already failed

Simplified to this point: Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct con_handler : std::enable_shared_from_this<con_handler> {
    using pointer = std::shared_ptr<con_handler>;
    con_handler(asio::any_io_executor ex) : sock(ex) {}

    tcp::socket& socket() { return sock; }

    void start() {
        auto self = shared_from_this();
        sock.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data), bind(&con_handler::handle_read, self, _1, _2));
        sock.async_write_some(asio::buffer(message), bind(&con_handler::handle_write, self, _1, _2));
    }

  private:
    void handle_read(boost::system::error_code const& err, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        std::cerr << "recv: " << bytes_transferred << "(" << err.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        if (!err) {
            std::string_view msg(data.data(), bytes_transferred);
            std::cout << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
        }
        // else sock.cancel();
    }

    void handle_write(boost::system::error_code const& err, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        std::cerr << "sent: " << bytes_transferred << "(" << err.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        if (!err)
            std::cout << "Server sent " << quoted(message) << std::endl;

        // else sock.cancel();
    }

    tcp::socket            sock;
    std::string            message = "Hello From Server!";
    std::array<char, 1024> data;
};

struct Server {
    Server(asio::any_io_executor ex) //
        : acceptor_(ex, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1234)) {
        start_accept();
    }

    void handle_accept(con_handler::pointer connection, boost::system::error_code const& err) {
        if (!err)
            connection->start();

        start_accept();
    }

  private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    void start_accept() {
        con_handler::pointer connection = std::make_shared<con_handler>(acceptor_.get_executor());

        acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(), bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, connection, _1));
    }
};

int main() try {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    Server           server(ioc.get_executor());
    ioc.run();
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

Local demo:

Asio version: get_io_service() indicates an ancient version of boost

instead of io_service references, pass around executors making the code less coupled and easier to maintain
don't use private constructors and new, in favor of make_shared
use the move-accept overload of async_accept so you don't have to violate encapsulation with socket() { return sock; }

Text protocols:

Consider making logical reads instead of read_some. E.g. decide on line-wise IO, so you read until the first newline (and also write messages with a newline terminator)

v2 Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct con_handler : std::enable_shared_from_this<con_handler> {
    con_handler(tcp::socket s) : sock(std::move(s)) {}

    void start() {
        do_read();
        async_write(sock, asio::buffer(message), //
                    bind(&con_handler::handle_write, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
    }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        async_read_until(sock, asio::dynamic_buffer(response), "\n",
                         bind(&con_handler::handle_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
    }

    void handle_read(boost::system::error_code const& err, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        std::cerr << "recv: " << bytes_transferred << "(" << err.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        if (!err) {
            auto msg = response.substr(0, bytes_transferred - 1);
            response.erase(0, bytes_transferred);

            std::cout << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
            do_read();
        }

        // else sock.cancel();
    }

    void handle_write(boost::system::error_code const& err, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        std::cerr << "sent: " << bytes_transferred << "(" << err.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        if (!err)
            std::cout << "Server sent " << quoted(message) << std::endl;

        // else sock.cancel();
    }

    tcp::socket sock;
    std::string message = "Hello From Server!\n", response;
};

struct Server {
    Server(asio::any_io_executor ex) : acceptor_(ex, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1234)) { accept_loop(); }

  private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    void accept_loop() {
        acceptor_.async_accept([this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            if (!ec)
                std::make_shared<con_handler>(std::move(s))->start();

            accept_loop();
        });
    }
};

int main() try {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    Server           server(ioc.get_executor());
    ioc.run();
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

With a more useful local demo:

